# Write JUnit test on controller in SpringBoot Without start application

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, controller, mockito

I am trying to test my controller method which is calling method of a dao class , now dao class has @Autowired repositry and method of dao class is also calling the repositry method.
I am ended up @mock repository in my test class too for mocking its behaviour.

test class:

```java
Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

Mockito.when(userRepository.findByEmailId("abc@gmail.com")).thenReturn(obj);
```

dao class:

```java
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

obj=userRepository.findByEmailId(email);
```

now, my test case is not running. i am trying to create a base class for all the @Autowiring.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock `UserRepository`, but the DAO instead which is the direct dependency of your Controller. Something like the following:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ControllerClassName.class)
public class ControllerClassNameTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DaoClassName dao;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(dao.whateverMethodYouWantToMock()).thenReturn(xyz);
    }

    // Your tests here

}
```

Keep in mind that you should test your Controllers with `MockMvc` to emulate a real HTTP call and not a direct method call. More information at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest.

Comment: but my dao method has a entity obj which is containing the value returned by the repository method. My repository.method is hitting the database. my dao class:- entity obj=repository.mymethod; some other work on obj ;

Comment: But if you don't want to start the application (aka do an integration test) you have to mock DAO and you will not hit the database.

Comment: okk, i will try. Thank u